# Checking Java minor version on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, upgrade, apt-get

I have Ununtu server with OpenJDK.
When I check Java version from shell, I get this:

```
# java -version
openjdk version "18.0.2-ea" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't know how to check is there any minor Java versions upgrades available (for example 18.0.5 or 18.1.0) which means not Java 19 or any other major versions.

Every attempt to search around for magic apt-get command ends with instructions on installing Java, not checking minor versions and upgrading minor versions.

Comment: Your package manager will tell you if there is an update available: `sudo apt update`

Comment: @g00se when I run `sudo apt update` I get advice to run `apt list --upgradable`. This one lists packages. So that's it? Is there a way to list available versions or even browse?

Comment: Yes you can follow that advice. You can also look for others with `apt-cache openjdk`

Comment: @g00se yes yes yes, `apt-cache search openjdk` is the one! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I forgot the word 'search' ;)